# reverse list using Node class in Java

Tags: java, list

Sorry about this very basic question I'm allowed to use only `Node<T>` class, I'm trying to write a method that reverses the list e.g from `2,4,6.8.10` to `10,8,6,4,2`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Node<T> {
private T value;

private Node<T> next;

public Node(T value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = null;
}

public Node(T value, Node<T> next) {
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

public T getValue() {
    return this.value;
}

public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.next != null;
}

public void setValue(T value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public Node<T> getNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node<T> next) {
    this.next = next;
}

public String toString()

{

    return value + "--->" + next;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<Integer>(2);
    Node<Integer> n2 = new Node<Integer>(4);
    Node<Integer> n3 = new Node<Integer>(6);
    Node<Integer> n4 = new Node<Integer>(8);
    Node<Integer> n5 = new Node<Integer>(10);
    n4.setNext(n5);
    n3.setNext(n4);
    n2.setNext(n3);
    n1.setNext(n2);

    reverse(n1);
}

private static void reverse(Node<Integer> l) {
    //
    Node<Integer> rev = new Node<Integer>(10);

    while (l.hasNext()) {

        rev.setNext(l.getNext());
        System.out.println(rev.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println(l.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full generic proposal:

```
class Node<T> {

   ...

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return value + (( next != null ) ? ( "--->" + next.toString()) : "" );
   }

   private Node<T> reverse( Function<Node<T>, Node<T>> factory, Node<T> n ) {
      final Node<T> node = factory.apply( this );
      node.setNext( n );
      if( hasNext()) {
         return getNext().reverse( factory, node );
      }
      return node;
   }

   public Node<T> reverse( Function<Node<T>, Node<T>> factory ) {
      return reverse( factory, null );
   }
}

public class ReverseList {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final Node<Integer> n1 = new Node<>(  2 );
      final Node<Integer> n2 = new Node<>(  4 );
      final Node<Integer> n3 = new Node<>(  6 );
      final Node<Integer> n4 = new Node<>(  8 );
      final Node<Integer> n5 = new Node<>( 10 );
      n4.setNext(n5);
      n3.setNext(n4);
      n2.setNext(n3);
      n1.setNext(n2);
      System.err.println( n1 );
      final Node<Integer> r = n1.reverse( n -> new Node<>( n.getValue()));
      System.err.println( r );
   }
}
```

Execution:

```
2--->4--->6--->8--->10
10--->8--->6--->4--->2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
private Node<T> reverse(Node<T> inputList) {
    if (inputList == null || inputList.getNext() == null)
        return inputList;

    Node<T> secondPart = inputList.getNext();
    inputList.setNext(null);
    Node<T> reversed = reverse(secondPart);
    secondPart.setNext(inputList);
    return reversed;
}
```

How does it work?

Example input: `[1, 5, 8, 9, 10]`

```
take 1 and reverse [5, 8, 9, 10]
  take 5 and reverse [8, 9, 10]
    take 8 and reverse [9, 10]
      take 9 and reverse [10]
      return [10, 9] and append 8
    return [10, 9, 8] and append 5
  return [10, 9, 8, 5] and append 1
return [10, 9, 8, 5, 1]
```

Comment: @Aubin, now it does ;)